# jQuery simple transition issue

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, transition, fadeout

I am developing a very simple one-page site here: http://dispose.co/dormstory/pod.html

As you can see I've got the content positioned absolutely, and when you click a link the former content fades out and the new content fades in. The only issue is that the size of the containing divs are left on the page, so when you transition from **Crew** to **Trailer** for example **the page remains 1000+px long**, because the **Crew** page is that long...

What would be a simple way to fix this issue? I thought it would have to do with setting some height to auto but that hasn't helped at all.

Perhaps I need to reload the page in between the fadeIn and fadeOut?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using `table td`s for your layout, instead of floating `div`s ?

I belive its because `table` and its native style, so I would suggest you try to change youre layout to the following:

```
<div>
    <div id="gutter">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="indiegogo">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for answering my question. Although both answers were valid I found this to be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple approach, you can try forcing the height on click of one of the links.

One way would be to put the height in a data attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-main-height="750px">trailer</a>
```

Then on click, grab that value:

```
var the_height = $(this).data("main-height");
```

then set it via jquery:

```
$("#contentarea").css("height", the_height);
```

If your page uses a plugin, then there is most likely a callback you can use before the transition.

I would suggest trying to turn on back button functionality as well.

-p